# get the content of android mobile

Tags: android

i would like to read the content of mobile like directories with sub directories as well as files which are available in android phone.

i have implemented an application for get the content of android phone as follows

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
// Browse in the following folder.
Uri startDir = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/"));
// Files and directories
intent.setDataAndType(startDir, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andexplorer.file");
// Optional filtering on file extension.
intent.putExtra("browser_filter_extension_whitelist", "*.xml,*.txt,*.jpg,*.mp3,*.zip");
// Title
intent.putExtra("explorer_title", "Open File...");
// Optional font scale
intent.putExtra("browser_list_fontscale", "120%");
// Optional 0=simple list, 1 = list with filename and size, 2 = list with filename, size and date.
intent.putExtra("browser_list_layout", "2");
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_FILE_REQUEST);
```

if i use above shown way i am getting force close error as:

**05-26 18:20:02.917: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26867): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=file:///sdcard typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andexplorer.file (has extras) }**

here how can i resolve the force close error issue? is there any another way to get the content of android phone?

please any body help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
final File dir = context.getFilesDir();
for (final File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
final File dir = new File("/sdcard"); 
for(final File file : dir.listFiles()){ 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
             // Browse in the following folder.
            Uri startDir = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

            // Files and directories
            intent.setDataAndType(startDir, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andexplorer.file");
             // Optional filtering on file extension.
            intent.putExtra("browser_filter_extension_whitelist", "*.xml,*.txt,*.jpg,*.mp3,*.zip");
            // Title
            intent.putExtra("explorer_title", "Open File...");
// Optional font scale
            intent.putExtra("browser_list_fontscale", "120%");
            // Optional 0=simple list, 1 = list with filename and size, 2 = list with filename, size and date.
            intent.putExtra("browser_list_layout", "2");
            startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_FILE_REQUEST);
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

You may not have AndExplorer (lysesoft.andexplorer.file) installed on your system.

Comment: how can i get AndExplorer(lysesoft.andexplorer.file) in to my system.where it is?

Comment: without supporting AndExplorer file.can i get the content of android phone like directories,files etc.,

Comment: No, you will have to code your own file manager to do that.  There are likely code sources online.

Answer (score -1):

1. Dropbox
2. Hit the Menu button
3. Choose *Upload here*