# How to find all files in the internal storage , for some application?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, storage

I have same application that has bugs and issues :), but the most interesting is the one that makes my application take from 2MB to 100 MB internal memory storage ...

Just looking the algorithm doesn't say much cause there is a lot of fuzzy logic. So is there any way to find all my files that are stored in my internal storage ?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but
try 
the following link

[get the content of android mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138927/get-the-content-of-android-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

1. Dropbox
2. Hit the Menu button
3. Choose *Upload here*